# Create custom validation on Firebase Database Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I want to create a chat application using firebase real time db, I already have my own server and my own authentication for my users and recipient.

So basically what I want to do is:

I want my server to able to generate room, and its room secret key, so only to people I share the secret key who can access the room, do read and write

maybe the flow is like this
1. The server create a POST using REST API to this url

```
curl -X PUT \
https://example-chat-92682.firebaseio.com/order-test.json \ -d 
'{ 
   "UB8Hdazo834-4760": {
     "secret": "secret123"
   }
 }'
```

So it will generate following structure

```
- order-test
    - UB8Hdazo834-4760
         secret: "secret123",
```

2. then I will send the chat room https://example-chat-92682.firebaseio.com/order-test/UB8Hdazo834-4760.json to users

I will send them in json like this

```
"room": "https://example-chat-92682.firebaseio.com/order-test/UB8Hdazo834-4760.json",
"secret": "secret123"
```

3. Users receive the payload and use it to join the chat using their ios or android, so the final structure will be like this

```
- order-test
    - UB8Hdazo834-4760
         secret: "secret123",
         - chat
             - Kifeisufsu23r
                 name: "Bob",
                 message: "How you doin?"
             - Ki4324ffs3fIF
                 name: "Alex",
                 message: "I am fine"
```

The question is, how do I make Firebase Database Rule to create read and write validation?
I have seen the doc, I can't use the Firebase Authentication since I have my own auth and have no control over the auth (different micro service)

the secret will be auto-generated, so there is no way I can hardcode the database rule

If you guys have any feedback on my data structure, I am more than welcome

Comment: If you have a server, you can [mint a custom token for Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) to ensure your users are also identified within Firebase. They would then surface as `auth` and `auth.uid` in the Firebase Database security rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a server, you can [mint a custom token for Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) to ensure your users are also identified within Firebase. They would then surface as `auth` and `auth.uid` in the Firebase Database security rules.

But in your current model, I'd recommend putting the secret into the key of the room:

- order-test

  - UB8Hdazo834-4760_secret123

    - chat

      - Kifeisufsu23r
         name: "Bob",
         message: "How you doin?"
      - Ki4324ffs3fIF
         name: "Alex",
         message: "I am fine"

Now you can easily secure access so that only users that know both the room ID and the secret can access it:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": false,
    "order-test": {
      "$roomIdAndSecret": {
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen.